# Rolling 12 months regardless of year in Django

Tags: django, time

How would I go about setting up a rolling 12 month period in Django without any year.

I am trying to plot the academic year but the problem I am finding mainly due to my lack of knowledge is that I have to set the year in `datetime`

I would like to try and create a start and end date for the academic year which runs from the beginning of April to the end of March every year however I have to include the year in all the objects such as datetime.

Is there a way for me to set a start and end date regardless of the year, the only way I can think of so far is to take the end of March as a start date and then count 12 months from then.

As always, thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you add more explanation? I did not get your question.

Comment: Updated, hopefully clearer now and Merry Christmas :)

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?  A beginning and end datetime?

Comment: A beginning time and end time regardless of current year.

Answer (score 0):

`timedelta` might be help full. check out [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

```
import datetime
start_date = datetime.datetime.now()
end_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=365)
```

Comment: Thanks the start date needs to be at the end of March every year?

Comment: Based on your question the start_date would be beginning of April and timedelta would be 364 days.

Comment: The problem is that that would only run for one year. I want to set date for every year?